# Select option not selectable in mobile if using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select option that is not working on mobile. After testing, if I remove jquery it works, but with it don't.

I am using framework7 plus i18n but I don't thing it's an issue with them. I got no errors in console, it just don't work. If I tap and hold on mobile it shows the options, but after that no.

I have a codepen with everything here: http://codepen.io/RogerHN/pen/bgvxeb

I pulling all the options from a variable, but it's working.

```
<select id="itemList" name="itemSelect" class="hide">
  <option data-i18n="[value]item;[text]item" value="item">Item</option>
</select>
```

Also I tried another select, and when I include jquery it doesn't work on mobile, but with pure javascript it works.

Comment: Check the console. When you click any of the 'edit' buttons you get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
`

Comment: Sorry it was part of the other function that I removed, now the pen is good, and still doesn't work. That error was separated from the main problem.